# Vue | How to import my .js file correctly?

Tags: jquery, tensorflow, vue.js, import

Sorry if my question will be dumb, but I am a newbie in Vue :( 
I'm experiencing some kind of paradox, definitely there is something that I am doing wrong. I have a .js file with some functions in jquery. I want to import it to my vue app. So I use in App.vue:

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric'
import '../src/main-copy.js'
```

In first line I import fabric to use canvas, and in second line I try to import my file, but it gets errors:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/main-copy.js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\path\vue-test\src\main-copy.js
    8:1   error  '$' is not defined                        no-undef
    9:35  error  'fabric' is not defined                   no-undef
  120:11  error  '$' is not defined                        no-undef
  162:12  error  'tf' is not defined                       no-undef
  164:22  error  'tf' is not defined                       no-undef
  167:25  error  'tf' is not defined                       no-undef
  170:24  error  'tf' is not defined                       no-undef
  171:28  error  'tf' is not defined                       no-undef
```

So I installed jquery and tensorflow with npm, and imported it to App.vue:

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric'
import { jquery } from 'jquery'
import { tensorflow } from 'tensorflow'
import '../src/main-copy.js'
```

But when I add this imports, I get new errors:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

C:\path\vue-test\src\App.vue
  11:10  error  'jquery' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
  12:10  error  'tensorflow' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

I even tried to add simple

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
```

to index.html, but with no result.
What I am doing wrong? Please help.

---

Part of main-copy.js:

```
var model;
var canvas;
var classNames = [];
var coords = [];
var mousePressed = false;

$(function() {
    canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    canvas.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
    canvas.isDrawingMode = 0;
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "black";
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 10;
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
        getFrame();
        mousePressed = false;
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
        mousePressed = true;
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
        recordCoor(e);
    });
});
```

Comment: Add contents of `main-copy.js`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I did, please see.

Comment: Add `import $ from "jquery";` in the beginning

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Now I get `10:8   error  '$' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars`

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing jquery with vuejs. $(function() is a short hand for document.ready, check out VueJS lifecycles.